# How to know when Linux has been awakened from standby mode?

Tags: c, linux, power-management, sysfs

I'm working on an ARM-based Linux computer that has enabled a few features of the ***sysfs power*** interface. I know how to send it to standby (writing "standby" to `/sys/power/state`) but I can't find how to acknowledge the wakeup (which I perform though a RTC setting an alarm in `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`)

From [the kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-power) I thought that I could do it by reading `wake_count`, but this is all I have available from the sysfs power management:

```
root@debian:/sys/power# ls -l
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K  2014-Apr-16  16:58:45 pm_async
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K  2014-Apr-16  16:58:45 state
```

Should I compile my kernel with any special configuration? By the way, I'm actually programming in C. is there any alternative to the *sysfs* interface?